# Upgrading Laravel from 4.2 to 5. How do I get a filter to work?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a method in my filters.php in my Laravel 4.2 app that looks like this:

```
    // Clean/self-updating URLs for property
    Route::filter('property-slug', function($route, $req)
    {
        $listing = $route->parameter('listing');

        if ($route->parameter('metainfo') != $listing->metainfo) {
            return Redirect::route('listing.full', [$listing->MLSNumber, $listing->metainfo]);
        }

    });
```

All this does is allow me to type in mydomain.com/property/21938281 (or some MLS number) and it redirects to the nice URL with the address slug (e.g. mydomain.com/property/21938281-123-main-street

Where do I put the new filters now?  I see that there is middleware for before and after but I'm not sure how to get this particular one to work since it doesn't really fit a before or an after.

Comment: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/upgrading-from-laravel-4-to-laravel-5#filters

Comment: Did you ever successfully rewrite this?  Could you post your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Create a middleware:

```
php artisan make:middleware AdminMiddleware
```

Modify it to your needs.

Open `app/Http/Kernel.php`, add something like:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class
];
```

Use in the `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('admin/accounts', ['middleware' => 'admin', function () {
    //
}]);
```

I had to move from filters to middleware a few days ago, since they are deprecated in 5.1.